# error al importar libreria en c++

Tags: c++

necesito ayuda. creé una libreria y al principio le puse el :

```
#ifndef _PILA_H
#define _PILA_H
......
......
#endif
```

pero me causa problemas al importarle en dos archivos .cpp diferentes, tambien la importo a otra libreria .h ambas librerias tienen los #ifdef ...

Me sale el error de Multiple definition

alguien que sepa cual es el problema??

este es el codigo de la libreria

```
#ifndef PILA_H
#define PILA_H

#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;


class Nodo {
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        Nodo *siguiente;
};


class Pila {
private:
    Nodo *tope;

public:
    Pila();
    void insertar(float x, float y);
    Nodo sacarPila();
    Nodo verTope();
    bool vacia();
};

Pila::Pila(){
    tope = NULL;
}

void Pila::insertar(float x, float y)
{
    Nodo *nuevo;
    nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo->x = x;
    nuevo->y = y;
    if (tope == NULL)
    {
        tope = nuevo;
        nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        nuevo->siguiente = tope;
        tope = nuevo;
    }
}


Nodo Pila::sacarPila(){
    if (tope != NULL)
    {
        Nodo *bor = tope;
        tope = tope->siguiente;
        return *bor;
    }
    else
    {
        Nodo *bor = NULL;
        return *bor;
    }
}

Nodo Pila::verTope(){
    if (tope != NULL)
        return *tope;
    else
    {
        Nodo *bor = NULL;
        return *bor;
    }
} 

bool Pila::vacia(){
    if (tope == NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}


#endif
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Amaury, ¿podrías poner el código de los ficheros donde incluyes pila.h? (al menos la parte donde se incluye).

Comment: puesss solo la incluyo como #include "pila.h" . Cuando solo importo a un archivo, funciona, pero cuando creo otro archivo me aparece el error, incluso prove poniendo   #pragma once   al inicio de la libreria pero no funciona, me aparece lo mismo

Comment: ¿No tienes un .cpp para pila?

Comment: No, solo tengo pila.h

Comment: Pues ese va a ser el problema. Llevo sin usar C/C++ mucho tiempo, pero me parece que el .h se procesa siempre que se incluye, lo que no se procesaría sería el código del .c/.cpp (y como tienes las funciones en el .h te daría el error de que se han declarado múltiples veces). Voy a buscar información online, prueba eso mientras tanto.

Comment: Sí, parece que va a ser eso. Hay una explicación aquí en el [sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425299/3695983)

Comment: me pareció ver algo al respecto. mmm Necesitaría  modificar el pila.h y solo definir los metodos y en el pila.cpp escribir el codigo de los metodos como tal?

Comment: Sí. Prueba eso y si funciona ponlo como respuesta referenciando el enlace que puse en el comentario arriba.